# Disable Chromes "articles for you"

Tags: chrome-for-android, google, google-now

The Google Android Chrome browser (which is the default browser on lots of Android devices) is displaying "suggested" news items on every new tab "articles for you".
There doesn't seem to be an option to disable this feature.

Can the new tab page be customized / configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tldr:
Disable the #enable-ntp-remote-suggestions flag in Chromes Dev settings.

Long version: Follow the steps described in here https://www.androidpolice.com/2017/04/27/customize-chromes-terrible-new-tab-page/